# Tikz positioning library has weird behavior with tkz-tab package in position of nodes

Tags: positioning, tikzlibrary, tkz-tab

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzTabInit[lgt=1.5, espcl=1.5]%
            {$x$/0.8, $f'(x)$/0.8, $f(x)$/1.6}{$-\infty$, $-\sqrt{3}$, $-1$}
        \tkzTabLine{,+,z,-,d}
        \tkzTabVar{-/$0$,+V+/,-DC-/$0$/$0$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If the library is deactivate, the nodes (zeros) are fine, but if the library is activate, the nodes aren't aligned. How can this be fixed?

[image: without positioning]

[image: with positioning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With positioning library, the syntax `above left=1pt` differs from the syntax `above left=1pt and 1pt`.
In the `tkz-tab` package, the styles of the node positions are defined as follows

```
\tikzset{low left/.style = {above left = \tkzTabDefaultSep}}
```

so if it changes to

```
\tikzset{low left/.style = {above left = \tkzTabDefaultSep and \tkzTabDefaultSep}}
```

then the problem with the alignment of the nodes is fixed.